# how to schedule a non-hidden task with schtasks?

Tags: windows, windows-task-scheduler

I've been trying to create a scheduled task from the command prompt. The task is created, but it runs hidden. Is there any way of running it in a non-hidden way? The process is very long and I would like to see what is going on...

I'm running it on a Vista, but the task is meant to run on pre-vista OS as well...

SCHTASKS /Create /RU \"NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM\" /SC DAILY /ST 00:00 /TN Backup /TR \"C:\Sis\Backup\Backup.vbs\" /F /V1

Tks,
Filipe Scur

Answer (score 0):

Running as NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM means it is a system task and will run hidden.
Try run as a different username.